# Исключение в c++

Tags: c++, исключения

Написана одна программа на с++,где есть вот такая функция

```
int get_independent_set(int u)
{
    if (I[u] != 0)
        return I[u];
    else
    {
        int children_sum = 0;
        int grandchildren_sum = 0;
            // цикл по всем детям
        for (int i = 0; i < G1[u].size(); i++)
            children_sum = children_sum + get_independent_set(G1[u][i]);
                // цикл по всем внукам
        for (int i = 0; i < K1[u].size(); i++)
            grandchildren_sum = grandchildren_sum + get_independent_set(K1[u][i]);
                    // запоминаем, чтобы не пересчитывать ещё раз
        I[u] = MAX(1 + grandchildren_sum, children_sum);
        return I[u];
    }
}
```

это функция для нахождения наибольшего независимого множества в графе. Так вот если в графе вершин около 100000,то вылетает исключение в файле xutility
вот в это месте

```
const _Ty2& _Get_second() const noexcept
        {   // return const reference to second
        return (_Myval2);
        }
    };
```

С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: Ощущение очень глубокой рекурсии...

Comment: И как это исправить? потому что есть в системе тест на 100000 вершин. и как вот мне его пройти?

Comment: Ну, проще всего - резко увеличить размер стека...

Comment: Спасибо,получилось)